# Count number of np.nan in a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a Pandas dataframe containing np.nan (Numpy not-a-number) values:

```
            field1
2020-12-24  NaN
2020-12-25  NaN
2020-12-26  1.0
2020-12-27  2.0
2020-12-28  NaN
2020-12-29  1.0
2020-12-30  2.0
```

(The index is a datetime.)
I would like to obtain a new dataframe with the start date and the number of times np.nan occurs, i.e.

```
            field1
2020-12-24  2
2020-12-28  1
```

I have tried this code:

```
prev = 1
for col_name, el in df.iterrows():
    print(el)
    if prev != np.nan and el[0] == np.nan:
        cnt = 1
    if prev == np.nan and el[0] == np.nan:
        cnt = cnt + 1
    if prev == np.nan and el[0] != np.nan:
        print(cnt)
    prev = el[0]
```

But it doesn't work as expected, and moreover I want to avoid "for" loops because I expect them to be very slow on bigger dataframes. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create groups by test non missing values by [`Series.notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.notna.html) with [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) and then filter only `NaN`s rows, then get counts by [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) and [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) and filter first duplicated rows by [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html):

```
m = df['field1'].notna()
s = m.cumsum()[~m]

df1 = s.map(s.value_counts())[~s.duplicated()].to_frame()
print (df1)
            field1
2020-12-24       2
2020-12-28       1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the sum of `isna()` on the column:

```
field1.isna().sum()
```

This is equivalent to taking the length of the column minus the count (which will exclude `NaN`'s)

```
len(df'field1') - df.count()
```

So you are thus able to count all the `Nan`'s in the database with the following command:

```
len(df) - df.count()
```

---

For rows you can use `axis=1`:

```
df.isna().sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: He wants the values in a row IIUC